# Unable to run program on Linux target

Tags: gcc, c

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04. I made a simple program (Hello World), and a makefile for it on my laptop and run it (./Simple), and everything worked.

Then I included the program (Simple.c) in the cross-compilation process (I just started to work on a bigger project).Simple.c is just this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(){
printf("Hello world \n"); 
return 0;}
```

The build worked, and I loaded this on the target, then I connected to the target using Serial port, and found the folder where my Simple should be, and then I tried to start it (./Simple), but I keep getting an `error:./Simple: line 1: syntax errir: unterminated quoted string.`
After deleting printf and #include. I also get an error

```
# ./Simple
./Simple: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "(".
```

I am not sure why I cant run the program that runs without a problem on my Ubuntu, and that doesnt report  an error during cross compilation.

Also, target is Realtek's RTL8685.
Result of file command on PC is:

```
#file ./Simple
./Simple: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

Result of file command on target is:

```
#file ./Simple
/bin/sh: file: not found
```

Comment: What is the target system? what does `file ./Simple` on the cross-compiled file say?

Comment: Target is Realtek's RTL8685. file ./Simple gives back: /bin/sh: file: not found

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1241025/edit) the original question above and add the new information.

Comment: If `file` is not available on the target OS, run it on the host before copying the file over. Basically, it looks like the executable has the wrong architecture for your target system (specifically, that the target OS doesn't have a loader for it, so is defaulting to the shell - see for example [Syntax error: “(” unexpected when execute a compiled c program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336452/65304)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @steeldriver , the problem was that the executable was not meant for the target system, because the cross compiler wasnt properly set in the makefile.